# Buttons added in bx-slider pager not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bxslider

I have added couple of buttons in bx-slider pager images, and calling respective function using ng-click (I am using anuglar) to remove and rotate images, , but these functions are not getting called when clicked on mobile device or in mobile responsive view in chrome. but working well in desktop and tablet view. I am seeing the classes getting changed while clicking on the button, but no function call. I am not able to figure out the exact problem.

I tried adding couple of test buttons and fucntions to check and found buttons in pager are not actually getting called in mobile.

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The error is that bxSlider use touch in mobile, it is for move slide with drag.

The fix is to add `touchEnabled: false` in your bxslider.